# extjs: obtain chart img without chart.save remote server?

Tags: extjs

I want to grab png of the chart clientside and push into img object without doing the chart.save remote server thing. Is this at all possible? tia.

Comment: What do you mean "without doing the chart.save"? You want to point it at your own server? If so, there's stuff in the docs about that.

Comment: The end result is to create a chart object in memory and paste its image onto the side of a three.js cube that resides on a canvas within an extjs panel. I need to instantiate about 20 different graphs and paste their image onto 20 cubes. I was hoping for a way of doing this on the client without network traffic. It's looking more and more like the best way is to write a translator that takes the extjs chart definition and converts into an object in the three.js world. I have read of people "screenscraping" with html/javascript so will research that before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible yes, we amended the URL on the `chart.save()` function in the Ext source code to our local server.

Once we redirected the save function, we pointed it at a C# handler which stripped out the SVG from the chart and used a server side SVG renderer function to produce an image.

What you do once it reaches the server will depend on your server side infrastructure.